# The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(MyProgram, int, Cursor, int) is undefined

Tags: android, cursor

Keep getting "The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(MyProgram, int, Cursor, int) is undefined" and am not sure why. Here is my code.

```
  Cursor c = mDbHelper.getAllTypes();
   startManagingCursor(c);
  SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item1, c, R.id.text1);
      setListAdapter(notes);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the API docs for [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) shows the following signature:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context ctx, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
```

So you need to modify your call accordingly.